# Python 'str' object has no attribute 'draw' when using Zelle graphics.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I am trying to create a simple GUI where a user enters some text and I bold certain words. I am using graphics library however my a getting a 'str' object has no attribute 'draw'. Also the window closes nearly instant.

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("Hangman", 600, 600)
win.setBackground("yellow")
textEntry = Entry(Point(233,200),50)
textEntry.draw(win)

# click the mouse to signal done entering text
win.getMouse()

text = textEntry.getText()
testText = Text(Point(150,15), text)
testText.draw(win)

finalOut = ""

outtxt = text
outtxtSplit = outtxt.split()
for word in outtxtSplit:
    if word == "bold":
        finalOut = finalOut + word.setStyle("bold")
    else:
        finalOut = finalOut + word

outtxt.draw(win)
exitText = Text(Point(200,50), outtxt)
exitText.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Comment: `outtxt.draw(win)` You are calling draw on a `str` object, the error message tells you that. What behaviour were you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Your

`outtxt = text`

Should be

```
outtxt = Text(Point(150,15), text)
                      /|\
                       | Put the size you want here.
```

In your code `outtxt` is the `text` *text* itself, so it has no method called `draw()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `Point()` argument to `Text()` pointed out in both answer and comment, this line simply won't work:

```
finalOut = finalOut + word.setStyle("bold")
```

As `finalOut` and `word` are Python `str` instances and the graphics.py `setStyle("bold")` method applies to `Text()` objects.

Fixing this, vs. dropping the feature, could be tricky as you'd need to collect a list of normal and bold `Text()` instances and draw them in a horizontal row with proper spacing.  graphics.py won't help much as I don't see any methods to get formatted text width.  It seems that ***style*** is all or nothing for the entire text message, not for individual elements of it.